# Can't hide actionbar menu item programatically

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to hide an Actionbar menu item if a shared preference is false.

I'm getting the shared preference as I want, but the menu item wont hide.

```
// Inflate a menu to be displayed in the toolbar
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_actionbar);       

// Enable disable set start page item
if(!sharedPref.getBoolean("enable_custom_startpage", false)) {
    toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.setasstartpage).setVisible(false);
}
```

What am i doing wrong??

Comment: try this.in your oncreate() method use this

getSupportActionBar().hide();
If your minSdkVersion is 11 or higher, instead use:

getActionBar().hide();

Comment: do  you want to hide the option menu only or the whole actionbar ?

Comment: Option menu item only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right place for doing this is `onPrepareOptionsMenu`. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29),

> Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is
>   called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can
>   use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise
>   dynamically modify the contents.

So, I would recommend you to override `onPrepareOptionsMenu` and then check for the Shared Prefs inside it and show menu accordingly. Something like,

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Enable disable set start page item
    if(!sharedPref.getBoolean("enable_custom_startpage", false)) {
        toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.setasstartpage).setVisible(false);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution. Sorry about the other post

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
mToolbar.getMenu().findItem(id).setEnabled(false);
```

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

I hope it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Get a MenuItem pointing to such item, call setVisible on it to adjust its visibility and then call invalidateOptionsMenu() on your activity so the ActionBar menu is adjusted accordingly.

Update: A MenuItem is not a regular view that's part of your layout. Its something special, completely different. Your code returns null for item and that's causing the crash. What you need instead is to do:

MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.addAction);

Answer (score 0):

1. Start by saving the menu globally in your activity-

   ```
   Menu menuu;

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   menuu=menu;
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
   return true;
   }
   ```
2. Have different menu.xml for you . one is having noitem and other is
   containing the items you want.

*menu_main.xml*

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.notification_service.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

*menu_blank.xml*

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.afixi.prasenjeetpati.notification_service.MainActivity">
</menu>
```

3. Now to remove the option menu at any time do this-

   ```
   menuu.clear();
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_blank, menuu);
   ```

   and to get back the normal menu-

   ```
   menuu.clear();
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menuu);
   ```